# Gimp: How to swap the left and right sides of an image?

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I want to "cut" the image in half, move the original left half of the image to the right, and move the original right half of the image to the left. How can I do that using Gimp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way: `Layer > Transform > Offset`.

[image: offset menu]

Select "%" in the offset field and set the X to 50.

[image: offset window]

You're gonna get a live preview.

[image]

Sorry, my Gimp speaks italian... but it should be clear as well.

Comment: perfect, this will save me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you image is a layer

- Duplicate the layer
- Make a rectangle selection over one half of the image. Instead of eyeballing the position you can edit the numbers directly in the tool options, and Gimp can do the math for you (you can use formulas in input fields) so if your image is 1200Wx800H you can get a selection with:

[image: Tool options]

- `Layer > Crop to selection`
- `Select > Invert` (selects the other half)
- Switch to the other layer and `Layer > Crop to selection`

[image: Result of crop]

- Use the move tool to move them with:

  - one hint: use `View > Snap to canvas edges` to help you position them
  - one warning: make sure the Move tool has `Move the active layer` checked (or use Shift-click to start Moving) and select the layer you want to move in the Layers list, otherwise you'll likely always move the topmost layer.

[image: Result of move]

Comment: There is a faster way you can use the offset filter with wrap around and do this in one step

Comment: @Jooja make that an answer (and pointing to `By width/2`) and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need exact halves (and assuming an even number of pixels of course), you can do this with a guide

1. Do *Image > Guides > New Guide by percent*, choose "Vertical" and set it to 50%
2. To split the Image you can either do as Xenoid suggests, or do *Image > Slice Using guides*.
3. Finally, in each of the sliced images, select all and copy, then back in your main image do *Edit > Paste As > New Layer*, move into position using snapping. And repeat for the other slice.

Answer (score -1):

For swapping the left and right sides of an image, I ended up creating this small demo youtube video here: https://youtu.be/QLu7nBKQhgU

Hope, this helps all. This concept can be applied for swapping the top and bottom portions of it too.

Discloser: I created this youtube video for the benefit of all, after hours of Googling for a solution.